# ErrorException (E_NOTICE) HELP unserialize(): Error at offset 20 of 33 bytes

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-4

I haven't work on my project Laravel 4 for about two days, and I don't think I make any changes to my code or database, when I land on a homepage, I no longer see my homepage.

I start to see this instead:

[image]

```
/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Store.php
```

How would one debug this?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the Laravel session data?  Looks like something was corrupted.

Comment: I updated my post.

Comment: Well is your database the session store?

Comment: Yes, I see something store in my database.

Comment: For some reasons, it work now. What the heck ? I don't understand this.

Comment: I think, your earlier suggestion is the answer to this post. `php artisan session:table`

Comment: @Devon : You answer it, if u want. I'll accept it since it is no longer happening.